# Are there names for the sums of every third element from the expansion of e^x, similar to how sinh and cosh are every other element?

Tags: functions

Without knowing if they have names, I'll call them ash, bsh, and csh. They would have the interesting property that $\frac{d\operatorname{ash}(x)}{dx} = \operatorname{bsh}\left(x\right), \frac{d\operatorname{bsh}\left(x\right)}{dx} = \operatorname{csh}\left(x\right), \frac{d\operatorname{csh}\left(x\right)}{dx} = \operatorname{ash}\left(x\right),$ and $\operatorname{ash}\left(x\right)+\operatorname{bsh}\left(x\right)+\operatorname{csh}\left(x\right) = e^x$

Comment: Another interesting property is that these functions form a basis for the set of solutions to the differential equation
$$
\frac {d^3y}{dx^3} - y = 0
$$

Comment: It's a bit of typing, but you can use \operatorname to get the proper font and spacing of uncommon function names, so \operatorname{ash}(x) gives $\operatorname{ash}(x)$

Comment: To further Ross's comment, `\mathrm{ash}` is a bit less typing (but doesn't always properly space the operator's name away from other characters).

Comment: @Kevin Another point is that you can express these nicely in terms of $e^x$. For instance, we have
$$
\operatorname{ash}(x) = \frac{e^{x} + e^{\omega x} + e^{\omega^2 x}}{3},
$$
where $\omega = \frac 12 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i = e^{2 \pi i/3}$.

Comment: updated MathJax

Comment: @Ben Thanks for that. imaginary numbers in exponents are beyond my intuition.

Comment: Do you mean $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^{3 n}}{(3 n)!};\;\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^{3 n+1}}{(3 n+1)!};\;\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^{3 n+2}}{(3 n+2)!}$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection

Comment: @KevinNowaczyk You could simply think of $e^{\omega x}$ as corresponding to plugging in $\omega x$ to the power seriees for $e^x$. An nice consequence of this form is that we can get a formula for the rest using calculus. For instance,
$$
\operatorname{bsh}(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{e^{x} + e^{\omega x} + e^{\omega^2 x}}{3} = \frac{e^{x} + \omega e^{\omega x} + \omega^2 e^{\omega^2 x}}{3}.
$$

Comment: @Ben thank you! From this I learned all about other fun stuff like raising e to the power of a matrix!

Answer (score 1):

Solving the system of equations without any boundary condition, we have
$$\color{red}{3 \,e^{\frac x 2}\operatorname{ash}(x)-\left(c_1+c_2+c_3\right) e^{\frac{3 x}2}=} $$
$$\sqrt{3}
   \left(c_2-c_3\right) \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)+\left(2
   c_1-c_2-c_3\right) \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)$$
$$\color{red}{3 \,e^{\frac x 2}\operatorname{bsh}(x)-\left(c_1+c_2+c_3\right) e^{\frac{3 x}2}=} $$
$$\sqrt{3} \left(c_3-c_1\right) \sin
   \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)-\left(c_1-2 c_2+c_3\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)$$
$$\color{red}{3 \,e^{\frac x 2}\operatorname{csh}(x)-\left(c_1+c_2+c_3\right) e^{\frac{3 x}2}=}$$
$$\sqrt{3} \left(c_1-c_2\right) \sin
   \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)-\left(c_1+c_2-2 c_3\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)$$
$$\color{blue}{\operatorname{ash}(x)+\operatorname{bsh}(x)+\operatorname{csh}(x)=\left(c_1+c_2+c_3\right) e^x}$$